# Using ANTLR4-Intellij-Adaptor library with UVL grammar - IntelliJ Custom Lanugage Support

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, intellij-plugin, lexer

I am currently developing an Intellij plugin to support UVL as a custom language. As there already exists an ANTLR4 grammar for UVL [1](https://github.com/Universal-Variability-Language/uvl-parser-java/blob/main/src/main/antlr4/de/vill/UVL.g4), I wanted to use this grammar for the parser and lexer as suggested in the IntelliJ docs. To do so, I need to use the antlr4-intellij-adaptor [2](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-intellij-adaptor).

There is also a sample plugin with custom grammar using this technique [3](https://github.com/antlr/jetbrains-plugin-sample), where the syntax highlighting for e.g. strings works perfectly fine for me. So my setup should be fine. But when using the UVL grammar instead, when running the plugin and trying to open a file (ending in .uvl) I just get a blank window. The grammar is generated without any errors and there is also no error output when running the plugin and opening a file which then stays blank.
I also tried another grammar for testing purposes, but this also does not work - same problem. Only the grammar from the sample plugin works...

It is very difficult for me to debug it, as there is no error output. Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong or anything I need to change in the UVL grammar to make it work with the adapter? Thanks for any help! If you want to have a look at my code: https://github.com/treufabian/IntelliJ-UVL-Plugin

Comment: Could you elaborate more. I've tried your plugin and I didn't get any blank window.

Comment: When I open a .uvl file with uvl content in it (of course with my plugin active), my editor keeps blank, as if it never finishes loading the file.

Comment: I don't have Ultimate license so I disabled/commented all Ultimate related stuff (LSP and so on) before running your plugin. Maybe it's the reason. Also I uncommented STRING highlighting in `UVLSyntaxHighlighter`. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/jDRd0LQ Patch: https://pastebin.com/TX77eHTE

Comment: Yeah, thats because your version is the one with the sample grammar activated (which works as mentioned in the original post). I have put multiple grammars in the UVL.g4 file for testing purposes.
Sorry, I should have mentioned that explicitly!

I have now activated the UVL grammar, now you should also get the blank window. (https://github.com/treufabian/IntelliJ-UVL-Plugin/commit/a22136c276006e0da3cf281257303e36ce0f1117)

Comment: Now I can reproduce it. I believe the reason is "Discontinuous sequence of tokens is generated by lexer" exception that's thrown by `ValidatingLexerWrapper.advance` method. I don't know why IDEA doesn't report it to a user and just shows a blank editor. You should report it to [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/). To fix the issue your lexer should produce a sequence of tokens without any gaps.